# How to loop over multiple levels of tag elements by xpath in Selenium or BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, html, selenium-webdriver, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am trying to create a data frame in python of a ecommerce site's menu items. Below is an example of what the menu looks like. It is very nested and has several submenus within the main navigation bar.

[Menu Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9KwcJ.png)

Because there are several submenus I am having trouble creating a loop that will parse out the values for all the elements at each level. Here is an example of what the HTML looks like.

[Full HTML Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c1OhM.png)

```
<ul class="c-nav-menu ''">
    <li class="dropDown hoverFade topNav category-6 c-furniture ">
        <a class="c-nav-category_link topnav-furniture" href="xx">
            <span>Furniture</span>
        </a>
        <div class="c-nav-columns hoverFadeTarget c-nav-columns-furniture "> 
            <div class="c-nav-columns_group columns_group-size--5">
                <div class="col col-0"> 
                    <div class="nav-columns-section-heading living-room-furniture">Living Room Furniture</div>
                        <ul>
                            <li>
                                <a href="xx2"> Sofa &amp; Sectional Collections
```

I would like the final data frame to look like this:

| Category 1 | Category 2 | Category 3 | Category 3 Link Path |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Furniture | Living Room Furniture | Sofas & Sectionals | https://www.xx./furniture/living_room/sofa |
| Furniture | Living Room Furniture | Chairs | https://www.xx./furniture/living_room/chairs |
| Furniture | Living Room Furniture | Coffee Tables | https://www.xx./furniture/living*room/coffee_*table |

I have tried using both beautiful soup and selenium to parse each of the levels out but have not been successful in getting it to iterate.

For Category 1 I used to below code and it gave me my expected result.

input:

```
nav = soup.find_all("a", {"class" : lambda L: L and L.startswith('c-nav-category_link topnav')})
for item in nav:
    level1 = {
        'cat_1': item.find("span").text}
    print(level1)
```

output:

```
{'cat_1': 'Furniture'}
{'cat_1': 'Outdoor & Garden'}
{'cat_1': 'Rugs'}...
```

This method also worked for Category 2, however, when I tried to repeat this for category 3, I was only able to pull out the first item under each submenu instead of all the items under each submenu.

input:

```
final_link = soup.find_all("div", {"class" : lambda L: L and L.startswith('col col-')},"li")
for final_item in final_link:
    level3 = {
        'cat_3': final_item.find("a").text.replace('\n',"")}
    print(level3)
```

output:

```
{'cat_3': 'Sofa & Sectional Collections'}
{'cat_3': 'Bedroom Collections'}
{'cat_3': 'Dining Collections'}...
```

This should return: Sofas & Sectionals, Sectionals, Sofas & Loveseats. But instead it skips to the next submenu. I also tried to parse using selenium and XPATH but was unsuccessful.

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
title = driver.find_elements(by=By.XPATH, value='//*[@id="topnav-container"]/ul/li')
for li in title:
    product_data = {'title': li.text}
print(product_data)
```

Would anyone have any suggestions on how to parse this correctly?

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/75240534/edit) your answer and provide a url to the site so we can test it ourselves.